# configure freetype with an error cannot find native C compiler

Tags: c, configure, freetype

I am trying to make freetype But configure with an error

My command

**./configure --host=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=$PWD/tmp**

The error info

```
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for windows.h... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
configure: error: cannot find native C compiler
make: *** [builds/unix/detect.mk:91: setup] Error 1
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Apparently your system provides neither "gcc" nor "cc" as its C compiler. Do you have a C compiler installed at all?

Comment: It looks like my Ubuntu iso got some problem. It looks good on another Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload another Ubuntu iso can fix it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).